# ASP.NET Web API + Angular + Azure AD B2C Authorize

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, angular, azure-ad-b2c

How to build protected Web API with Angular and Azure AD B2C ?
I follow: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/

But I am not sure about using cookie authentication with Web API. Any idea how I should do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: https://cgillum.tech/2016/08/10/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c-part-2/

Should bring AD B2C as Authentication Provider of Azure App Service, so next you work with Easy Auth of Azure App Service that support cookie for login.

Above post also include an example for SPA app already.